# Android - Display Query's Result in an Activity

Tags: java, android, sql

I have the result of a sql query expressed in this way :

```
//The column attributes of a result table
ArrayList<String> columns_attributes;
// This contains the data of every row of the result
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows_data;
```

How can i dinamically display it on an activity ? Thanks

Comment: Look up ListView -> you can display the contents of the ArrayList in the ListView. Pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list.add("Android");
        list.add("iPhone");
        list.add("Windows");
        list.add("Blackberry");
        list.add("Mac");
        list.add("Laptop");
        list.add("LCD");
        list.add("Dell");

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_view_item, list);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: " + list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.listviewalert.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over these list with simple for loops like this:

```
// for columns
for (String colAttr : columns_attributes) {
    // do something with the string value
}

// for rows
for (List<String> row : rows_data) {
    for (String rowAttr : row) {
        // do something with the string value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a dynamic amount of data, a `ListView` is recommended to do the job. If you just want to display those strings, you can use a `ListActivity` and assign a `ArrayAdapter` to that ListView with the `setListAdapter()` method.

You may want to check this tutorial to get this done.

http://androidexample.com/Create_Listview_With_ListActivity_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=66